# Angularjs why for/loop overriding the array items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use twitch api and I need to know which user is online

```
//Initialize the App
var channels = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var app = angular.module('Twitch', []);

//main controller

app.controller("MainController", function ($scope, $http) {

    //Where controller variables are assigned 

    // create the game Object
    var result = {};
    $scope.results = [];
    var stream = {};
    var care = "";
    $scope.streams = [];
    var url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/';

    for (var x = 0; x < channels.length; x++) {

        $http.jsonp(url + channels[x] + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function (data) {
            result = data;
            var id = data._id;
            var name = data.name;

            $scope.url = "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/" + name + "-profile_image-" + id + "-300x300.jpeg";
            $scope.image = data.logo;
            $scope.name = data.name;
            $scope.status = data.status;

            $http.jsonp("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + channels[x] + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success(function (data) {
                var streaming = (data.stream === null) ? false : true;
                if (streaming) {
                    result.off = 'online';
                    var streamTitle = data.stream.channel.status;

                    if (streamTitle.length > 36) {
                        streamTitle = streamTitle.substring(0, 33);
                        streamTitle += '...';
                    }
                    result.streamTitle = streamTitle;
                } else {
                    result.off = 'offline';
                    data.streamTitle = '';
                }
                result.username = channels[x];
            });

            $scope.results.push(result);

            console.log(result);
        }).error(function (data) {
            // something went wrong :(
            console.log('Got nothing');
        });
    }
});
```

I created variable which is `result.off` to hold the status value for the user

(online/offline) 
and i'm showing this values inside table

```
<div class="container text-center text-middle" ng-controller='MainController'>
    <table class="table" ng-repeat="result in results">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-class="satus">
                <td><a class="media-left" href="#">
                    <img ng-src={{result.logo}} alt="image" class="img-circle img-middle " width='50px'> </a></td>
                <td>
                    <h4 class="media-heading">{{result.name}} <span class="label"><p>{{result.off}}</p></span></h4>
                </td>
                <td><h4>{{result.status}}</h4></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

the expression result.off only shows the last user status in the list

Comment: EDIT :  I created variable which is reult.off (not user.off) to hold the status value for the user

(onlin/offline) and i'm showing this values inside table

Comment: in your result array check for  result.off value for each user   contains data or not

Comment: only the last object that has off property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the `result` variable inside the for - loop

when you do `result = data;` you just overwrite the value and push it.

The resulting array is a list of the same object

Answer (score 0):

the variable result empty object should be implemented after the loop starts

so it can be iterated inside the loop otherwise the value will be overritten

```
channels.forEach(function(channel) {
   $http.jsonp(url + channel + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data) {
       var result = {};
```